# deleting sms from thread SQLite Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, sms

[image]I am developing an application in which when sms is received it is stored in sqlite database and is shown in Listview. If different sms are received from same number then the sms is saved in the form of thread just like in the normal messaging apps.
Now the problem is that I am not been able to delete the inside messages inside a number. I can delete the whole thread but not one by one messages inside a thread.
Don't know why is this happening.
This is the query for creating a table:

```
public static final String query_createSMSTablee = "create table " + "smss" + "(" + "id" + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + "contactnumber" + " text, " + "contactname" + " text," + "message" + " text," + "date" + " text)";
```

Now to make messages as thread i did this:

```
String query = "select  message  from " + "smss"+ " where " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + mdataa + "\"" ;
```

Where "mdataa" contains the number of the sender. "message" contains only the message content
so in this way this becomes a thread i.e. only showing messages from specific number inside thread.
Now when i long tap on message and try to delete by this query this show me error:

```
String deleteScreenedMessage = "delete from " + "smss" + " where " + "id" + " = \"" + id + " AND " + "message" + " = \"" + selectedFromList + " AND " + "contactnumber" + " = \"" + mdataa + "\"" ;
DBtableforNotSpam smsDb = new DBtableforNotSpam(Conversation.this);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsDb.getWritableDatabase();
dbw.execSQL(deleteScreenedMessage);
dbw.close();
```

Here "selectedFromList" represents the content of the message and mdataa contains the number of the sender.
But this query is giving force stop error and says Sqlite Exception.
Please Help anyone

Comment: Its always necessary to add crash logs too

Comment: iam going to edit the post

Comment: your error log clearly says that you are missing quotes in your  sql query, please check it

Comment: I checked many times but still i havent found any thing in query :(

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is improper, you are jungling with quotes,

try this query,

```
String deleteScreenedMessage = "delete from " + "smss" + " where " + "id" + " 
       = " + id + " AND " + "message" + "='" + selectedFromList + "' AND " + 
                                                "contactnumber" + " ='" + mdataa +"'" ;
```